# CalendarView Not Updating Correctly

Tags: android, kotlin

I am loading events into my custom calendarView I built using kizitonwose's Calendar class:
https://github.com/kizitonwose/Calendar.git

I am able to get the events from my Room DB by loading the data into an array and stepping through it to load them into the view:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel
        binding = CalendarFragmentBinding.bind(view)
        binding.exThreeRv.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = eventsAdapter
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL))
        }
    
        binding.viewCalendar.monthScrollListener = {
            activityToolbar.title = if (it.yearMonth.year == today.year) {
                titleSameYearFormatter.format(it.yearMonth)
            } else {
                titleFormatter.format(it.yearMonth)
            }
        }
    
        activityToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    
        val allEvents = viewModel.allEvents
    
        val daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek()
        val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()
        val startMonth = currentMonth.minusMonths(50)
        val endMonth = currentMonth.plusMonths(50)
        configureBinders(daysOfWeek)
        binding.viewCalendar.apply {
            setup(startMonth, endMonth, daysOfWeek.first())
            scrollToMonth(currentMonth)
        }
    
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Show today's events initially.
            binding.viewCalendar.post { selectDate(today) }
        }
    
        for (item in allEvents) {
            val currentDate = item.date
            val currentIssueType = item.eventType
            val id = item.id
            println("currentIssueType eventType ------------> $currentIssueType")
    
            loadEvent(id, currentDate, currentIssueType)
            viewModel.deleteEvent(currentDate, currentIssueType)
            selectDate(currentDate)
        }
        val month = currentMonth
        binding.exThreeAddButton.setOnClickListener { inputDialog()}
    }
```

The configureBinders class creates the calendar correctly:

```
private fun configureBinders(daysOfWeek: List<DayOfWeek>) {
        class DayViewContainer(view: View) : ViewContainer(view) {
            lateinit var day: CalendarDay
            val binding = com.richeypro.android.justadot.databinding.CalendarDayBinding.bind(view)

            init {
                view.setOnClickListener {
                    if (day.position == DayPosition.MonthDate) {
                        selectDate(day.date)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        binding.viewCalendar.dayBinder = object : MonthDayBinder<DayViewContainer> {
            override fun create(view: View) = DayViewContainer(view)
            override fun bind(container: DayViewContainer, data: CalendarDay) {
                container.day = data
                val textView = container.binding.calendarDayText
                newEvent?.date
                var eventEventType = eventType
                val dotView = container.binding.exThreeDotView

                textView.text = data.date.dayOfMonth.toString()

                if (data.position == DayPosition.MonthDate) {
                    textView.makeVisible()
                    when (data.date) {
                        today -> {
                            textView.setTextColorRes(R.color.example_3_white)
                            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_today_bg)
                            dotView.makeInVisible()
                        }
                        selectedDate -> {
                            textView.setTextColorRes(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_selected_bg)
                            dotView.makeInVisible()
                        }
                        else -> {
                                when (eventEventType) {
                                    "Light" -> {
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_light_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                    "Medium" -> {
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_medium_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                    "Heavy" -> {
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_heavy_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                    "Spotting" -> {
                                        dotView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_spotting_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                    "Start" -> {
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_start_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                    "Future" -> {
                                        dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_future_bg)
                                        eventEventType = ""
                                    }
                                }
                                textView.setTextColorRes(R.color.example_3_black)
                                textView.background = null
                                dotView.isVisible = events[data.date].orEmpty().isNotEmpty()
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    textView.makeInVisible()
                    dotView.makeInVisible()
                }
            }
        }

        class MonthViewContainer(view: View) : ViewContainer(view) {
            val legendLayout = CalendarHeaderBinding.bind(view).legendLayout.root
        }
        binding.viewCalendar.monthHeaderBinder =
            object : MonthHeaderFooterBinder<MonthViewContainer> {
                override fun create(view: View) = MonthViewContainer(view)
                override fun bind(container: MonthViewContainer, data: CalendarMonth) {
                    // Setup each header day eventType if we have not done that already.
                    if (container.legendLayout.tag == null) {
                        container.legendLayout.tag = data.yearMonth
                        container.legendLayout.children.map { it as TextView }
                            .forEachIndexed { index, tv ->
                                tv.text = daysOfWeek[index].name.first().toString()
                                tv.setTextColorRes(R.color.black)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

But, after I cycle through my array of events, the view shows the assigned ImageResource of whatever the last loaded eventType. I have multiple ways to load in the events (currently walking through the array and using the SaveEvent function), but the view keeps misassigning the image on each day with an event saved to it.

Is there a better way to load in the events from my DB?

I tried loading the events with a separate function, but was running into an error.

I am expecting the saved events to load into the view and be assigned the imageView that corresponds to the eventType.